# Roast chicken cooking time

Tags: chicken

What is the best method for determining when a roast chicken is done cooking? Many of the methods I have seen online provide approximate time ranges for cooking dependent on the weight of the chicken. I don’t usually have a scale handy when I cook, especially if I’m only cooking part of the chicken. Are there any precise approaches I can use that are easily accessible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instant read thermometer in your kitchen, that can be particularly useful for determining when all kinds of meats are done cooking. For chicken, I would insert the thermometer into the inner thigh of the chicken (try to avoid the bone) and check for a temperature of 165 degrees F. Once the thermometer reads that temperature, the chicken should be ready.

Answer (score 1):

Without a thermometer it is hard(er) to know if the chicken is cooked.

Whole chicken are forgiving you can over cook it a little bit without much harm (mostly being too dry).

one way to know if the chicken is cooked, is to check if the legs pull apart easily or if the meat feels firm ([not precise](https://www.foodandwine.com/blogs/how-tell-when-roast-chicken-done))

another way is to pierce the meat and see if the liquid coming out is running clear (but it is [**not precise**](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/10433-cook-until-the-juices-run-clear-fact-or-fiction))

another way would be to slice into the meat and see if it is cooked.